# What is a finitely connected domain?

Tags: reference-request, definition

The paper *Chang, S.-Y. A. and Yang, P. C.: Conformal deformation of metrics on S 2 . J. Differential Geom., 27(2), 1988* ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214441783), [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=925123)) states in Proposition 2.3 that Moser's inequality holds for

> a piecewise, bounded, finitely connected domain in the plane with
> finite number of vertices.

Unfortunately, the term “finitely connected“ is not defined in the paper and Google is of little help to me.

I also asked this question to a colleague who remembered running into the same issue and, being better at using Google than I am, finding *multiple* definitions which (at least on first sight) disagreed. In their case this was not too worrisome as they were studying convex domains which fulfill all these conditions. However, I would be interested what precisely is needed for the cited proposition.

Thus, I am asking for reference introducing this term and perhaps also for a discussion of different definitions. (Perhaps they all agree?)

**Edit:** Cross-posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421658/what-is-a-fintelty-connected-domain).

Comment: See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Multiply-connected_domain